# How do I convert a list of tuples to a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples, like so:

```
lst_of_tpls = [(1, 'test2', 3, 4),(11, 'test12', 13, 14),(21, 'test22', 23,24)]
```

And I would like to convert it to a dictionary so that it looks like this:

```
mykeys = ['ones', 'text', 'threes', 'fours']
mydict = {'ones': [1,11,21], 'text':['test2','test12','test22'], 
          'threes': [3,13,23], 'fours':[4,14,24]}
```

I have tried to enumerate the `lst_of_tpls`like so:

```
mydict = dict.fromkeys(mykeys, [])
for count, (ones, text, threes, fours) in enumerate(lst_of_tpls):
    mydict['ones'].append(ones)
```

but this puts the values I would like to see in 'ones' also in the other "categories":

```
{'ones': [1, 11, 21], 'text': [1, 11, 21], 'threes': [1, 11, 21], 'fours': [1, 11, 21]}
```

Also, I would like to keep `mykeys` flexible.

Comment: @BearBrown You don't have to agree? Not sure why you're telling me this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply `zip` twice to find the proper pairings:

```
lst_of_tpls = [(1, 'test2', 3, 4),(11, 'test12', 13, 14),(21, 'test22', 23,24)]
mykeys = ['ones', 'text', 'threes', 'fours']
new_d = {a:list(b) for a, b in zip(mykeys, zip(*lst_of_tpls))}
```

Output:

```
{
 'ones': [1, 11, 21],
 'text': ['test2', 'test12', 'test22'],
 'threes': [3, 13, 23],
 'fours': [4, 14, 24]
}
```

Comment: Ok, cool that works. 
A lot of new syntax for me; let's see if I understand it: `zip(*lst_of_tpls)` returns an iterator with the first, second, ... element of the tuples. The outer zip adds the keys to that. So now I have an iterator for key, tuple pairs. Then with this iterator I generate the dictionary and on the fly I convert the tuples the first zip would give me to a list.

Comment: @evilolive That is correct. `zip(*lst_of_tpls)` pairs the elements in `lst_of_tpls`, and the second `zip` pairs each element in `mykeys` with each element in `zip(*lst_of_tpls)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass to dict tuples of (key, value), it's twice faster than use dictionary comprehension

```
lst_of_tpls = [(1, "test2", 3, 4), (11, "test12", 13, 14), (21, "test22", 23, 24)]
mykeys = ["ones", "text", "threes", "fours"]
my_dict = dict(zip(mykeys, zip(*lst_of_tpls)))
```

Output:

```
{'ones': (1, 11, 21),
 'text': ('test2', 'test12', 'test22'),
 'threes': (3, 13, 23),
 'fours': (4, 14, 24)}
```

Profiler example:

```
lst_of_tpls = [(1, "test2", 3, 4), (11, "test12", 13, 14), (21, "test22", 23, 24)]
mykeys = ["ones", "text", "threes", "fours"]


def dict_comprehension():
    return {a: list(b) for a, b in zip(mykeys, zip(*lst_of_tpls))}


def dict_generator():
    return dict(zip(mykeys, zip(*lst_of_tpls)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import timeit

    funcs = (dict_comprehension, dict_generator)
    for f in funcs:
        result = timeit.timeit(f, number=10000, globals=globals())
        print(f"{f.__name__}: {result:.5f}")


dict_comprehension: 0.05009 
dict_generator: 0.02468
```

Comment: Interesting. Can you try to explain what the difference between the dict-comprehension and the creation of a new dict(...) is? Is this a general rule that also applies to [...] vs. list(...) creation?